# nexus-staging-maven-plugin: maven deploy failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing

Tags: java, maven, maven-central, java-17

This worked fine for me be building under Java 8. Now under Java 17.01 I get this when I do mvn deploy.

mvn install works fine. I tried 3.6.3 and 3.8.4 and updated (I think) all my plugins to the newest versions.

Any ideas?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) on project persism: Execution injected-nexus-deploy of goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:de
ploy failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null


[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @149f5761
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) on project persism: Execution injected-nexus-deploy of goal org.sona
type.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution injected-nexus-deploy of goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.son
atype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
```

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.github.sproket</groupId>
    <artifactId>persism</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>./src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>./test</testSourceDirectory>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>./test</directory>
                <!--                <includes>-->
                <!--                    <include>*.*</include>-->
                <!--                </includes>-->
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <!-- MSSQL does not seem to able to connect with 16 -->
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
<!--                    <compilerArgs>-->
<!--                        <arg>-parameters</arg>-->
<!--                    </compilerArgs>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Automatic-Module-Name>sproket.github.io.persism</Automatic-Module-Name>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludePackageNames>net.sf.persism.log*;net.sf.persism.logging.*</excludePackageNames>
                    <source>17</source>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludedGroups>net.sf.persism.categories.ExternalDB,net.sf.persism.categories.TestContainerDB
                    </excludedGroups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.8</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                    <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <name>persism</name>
    <description>A zero ceremony ORM for Java</description>
    <url>https://github.com/sproket/Persism</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>BSD-3-Clause License</name>
            <url>https://github.com/sproket/Persism/blob/master/license.txt</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Dan Howard</name>
            <email>--------------------------</email>
            <organization>io.github</organization>
            <organizationUrl>https://sproket.github.io/Persism/</organizationUrl>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/sproket/Persism.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://github.com/sproket/Persism.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/sproket/Persism</url>
    </scm>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>include-test-containers-db</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludedGroups>net.sf.persism.categories.ExternalDB</excludedGroups>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>exclude-test-containers-db</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludedGroups>net.sf.persism.categories.TestContainerDB</excludedGroups>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Automatic-Module-Name>sproket.github.io.persism</Automatic-Module-Name>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-sources</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <release>17</release>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.carrotsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-benchmarks</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaybird</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.java8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.firebirdsql</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebird-testcontainers-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- using older version as 2.5.1 collides with ucanaccess -->
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <!--            <classifier>debug</classifier>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.8.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- OR -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.1.jre8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssqlserver</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.23</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>21.3.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>11.2.0.4</version>-->
        <!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1004-jdbc41</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.34.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ucanaccess</groupId>
            <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
            <artifactId>informix-jdbc-complete</artifactId>
            <version>4.50.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.toddfast.typeconverter</groupId>
            <artifactId>typeconverter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin -->
        <!-- DOES NOT WORK with JAVA 8 + -->
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>2.7</version>-->
        <!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--            <exclusions>-->
        <!--                <exclusion>-->
        <!--                    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>-->
        <!--                    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>-->
        <!--                </exclusion>-->
        <!--            </exclusions>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: First is there a good reason why you have defined `<sourceDirectory>./src</sourceDirectory>` second can you please check what `mvn --version` exactly tells you ...I suppose the nexus staging plugin has issues with JDK17? If so you have to go via maven-deploy-plugin instead...

Comment: Sounds like the plugin is not updated for the new module system.  Is there a newer version?

Comment: I checked the plugin versions. They seem up to date. @khmarbaise what do you mean "go via maven-deploy-plugin instead" ?

Comment: There is no updated version for the nexus-staging-plugin available. My suggestion was simply remove the nexus-staging-plugin and just do a `mvn deploy` ...(define the version of the maven-deploy-plugin...that's it... You have to close the release repository on Nexus manually...

Comment: I could try it under Java 16 maybe. OK I'll look into that. I created a case at sonatype as well.

Comment: @khmarbaise I am running mvn deploy.

Comment: @khmarbaise Hey thanks! That worked somehow! I just commented the nexus plugin and put maven-deploy-plugin with version. I don't know how this worked but it did!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update**: Version 1.6.13 has been released and should fix this issue!

---

This is actually a known bug, which is now open for quite a while: [OSSRH-66257](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-66257). There are two known workarounds:

#### 1. Open Modules

As a workaround, use `--add-opens` to give the library causing the problem access to the required classes:

```bash
export MAVEN_OPTS="--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED"
mvn deploy
```

#### 2. Manage Upstream Dependencies

Or you can update the library that causes the problem:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.8</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
    <nexusUrl>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
    <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
      <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.15</version> <!-- apparently this needs to be exactly this version -->
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: commented that plugin and used   maven-deploy-plugin but still I can't release since the gpg now generates .md5 and sha1 files instead of .asc files. Any ideas?

Comment: Trying this method failed for the same reason. The .asc files are not there. :( This used to work.

Comment: No idea, maybe the `maven-gpg-plugin` doesn't find a gpg key. That is a completely unrelated question, though.

Comment: Hey thanks. I didn't know we could override plugin dependencies.  It all worked fine.

Comment: #2 Worked for me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: These workarounds don't work for me. Gives me the error: `Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution injected-nexus-deploy of goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.13:deploy failed: 400 - Bad Request`

Comment: 1.6.13 does not appear to solve this: ```Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.13:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) on project rewrite-documentation: Execution injected-nexus-deploy of goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.13:deploy failed: A message body reader for Java class com.sonatype.nexus.staging.api.dto.StagingProfileRepositoryDTO, and Java type class com.sonatype.nexus.staging.api.dto.StagingProfileRepositoryDTO, and MIME media type text/html was not found -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: "Version 1.6.13" solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

There are some broken internal dependencies in the library

Updating nexus-staging-maven-plugin to 1.6.13 will solve your problem:

```
 <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.6.13</version>
```

Comment: I've got 1.6.13 and I'm still getting the same issue described here when trying to publish to Maven.

Comment: Same here. 1.6.13 does not solve this.

Comment: Bit different issue with 1.6.13, but similar: Unable to make field protected transient int java.util.AbstractList.modCount accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @53125718